# Why does parseInt return a different result to toFixed?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(typeof(parseInt((0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1)))); // number
console.log((0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1) == 0.3); // true
console.log((parseInt((0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1))) === 0.3); // false
```

Can someone please explain why the last statement does not return true?

Comment: Because `parseInt(0.3)` gives you 0

Answer (score 7):

`parseInt` will try to turn its argument into an **int** (integer). Decimal values will turn into integers. So

```
(0.1+0.2).toFixed(1)
```

turns into `0.3`, and

```
parseInt((0.1+0.2).toFixed(1))
```

turns into 0 (because `parseInt` floors non-integers, and 0.3 floored is 0).

If you just want to cast to number, use `Number` instead:

```js
console.log((Number((0.1+0.2).toFixed(1)))===0.3);
```

Keep in mind that due to floating-point weirdness, `0.1 + 0.2` results in `0.30000000000000004` - that's why calling `toFixed` on it first, to trim off some of the decimal points, is needed to compare it against `0.3` properly.

Comment: "turns into 0 (because 0 is the closest integer to 0.3)." - It actually floors the number. `parseInt(0.9)` would be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `parseInt(0.1 + 0.2)`. `parseInt` converts it to an integer and acts like `floor`, so `parseInt(0.3)` is giving 0

Answer (score 1):

Remember that parseInt() converts to an integer, so JavaScript rounds.

So:

1. `parseInt(0.1+0.2)` always returns 0. 0 is a number so this returns true.
2. `(0.1 + 0.3)` returns 0.3, meaning that this statement is true.
3. `parseInt(0.1 + 0.3)` rounds to 0 so this returns false.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt will retrieve only integer value.
In your case, parseInt(0.3) will return 0 which is not equal to 0.3
Go with Number(0.3) instead of using parseInt.